# azure table storage and python

Tags: python, azure

When reading the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/query-timeout-and-pagination) on retrieving entities from tables in table storage I came across the statement:
"It is possible for a query to return no results but to still return a continuation header."

In my code I am running into this situation where the time it takes to actually begin returning data is generally minutes and then more minutes to get the data.

I am wondering how to speed this process up, or avoid the empty returns of data.

Comment: Without you showing the type of query you're doing, there's no way to answer this. Queries don't just take minutes to return data. Please edit your question to show your query and how you're executing it via python.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, it sounds like you want to only get the continuation header without the query data for speeding up the pagination retrieve performance.

According to the REST API [`Query Entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/query-entities) of Table Storage, the official pagination way is that do the `GET` request to get the `x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey` & `x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey` value from the response header of the query entities operation to continuous to query the next dataset when the number of data retrieved exceed 1000 records. And there is no `HEAD` method for querying entities. So I think thoughts of you might be using `HEAD` request to do the continuous query operation.

I tried to do the `HEAD` request to get the required parameters of pagination via `Postman` tool, but I discovered there is not the `x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey` & `x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey` values in the response headers, please see below.

[image]

So it's not possible for a query to return no results but to still return a continuation header.